# Uncheck a specific checkedistbox item in powershell gui

Tags: powershell, user-interface

I currently have a powershell GUI containing a checkedListBox. What I'm trying to do is if a certain checkbox is checked, I want it to make sure that the other is unchecked. Does anybody have any idea how I can do this with powershell?

Comment: Provide some sample code!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to attach a function to the CheckedListBox.[ItemChecked](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.itemcheck.aspx) event.

```
## build a function to handle the ItemChecked event
function Handle-ItemChecked($sender, $args)
{
    ## do something here to change the state of the other
    ## checkbox. the box the user clicked is passed in 
    ## through $args. (See [ItemCheckEventArgs][2] on MSDN)
}

## listen for the event
$form.checkedListBox1.add_ItemChecked({ Handle-ItemChecked })
```

If your handler code is not too complicated, you could probably put it inside the { } rather than declaring another function. However, I think the approach above is more readable.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. For anybody looking how to check\uncheck a checkedlistbox item, here's what I finally found that worked.

Comment: $checkedListBox1.SetItemCheckState(i, 'Unchecked')